# Big O Recursive Method

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I have a method called binary sum

```
Algorithm BinarySum(A, i, n):
Input: An array A and integers i and n
Output: The sum of the n integers in A starting at index i
if n = 1 then
    return A[i]
return BinarySum(A, i, n/ 2) + BinarySum(A, i + n/ 2, n/ 2)
```

Ignoring the fact of making a simple problem complicated I have been asked to find the Big O. Here is my thought process. For an array of size N I will be making 1 + 2 + 4 ..  + N recursive calls. This is close to half the sum from 1 to N so I will say it is about N(N + 1)/4. After making this many calls now I need to add them together. So once again I need to perform N(N+1)/4 additions. Adding them together we are left with N^2 as the dominate term.
So would the big O of this algorithm be O(N^2)? Or am I doing something wrong. It feels strange to have binary recursion and not have a 2^n or log n in the final answer

Comment: Your algorithm is defined by this recurrence `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n`. You can do a tree analysis on it to find the asymptotic solution

Comment: @Dummy not `+ n` but `+ O(1)`; this gives a different result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *are* in-fact `2^n` and `log n` terms in the final result... sort of.

For each call to a sub-array of length `n`, two recursive calls are made to both halves of this array, plus a constant amount of work (if-statement, addition, pushing onto the call stack etc). Thus the recurrence relation is given by:

[image]

At this point we *could* just use the *Master theorem* to directly arrive at the final result - `O(n)`. But let's instead derive it by repeated expansion:

[image]

The stopping condition `n = 1` gives the maximum value of `m` (ignoring rounding):

[image]

In step **(*)** we used the standard formula for geometric series. So as you can see the answer does involve `log n` and `2^n` terms in a sense, but they "cancel" out to give a simple linear term, which is the same as for a simple loop.